# Как разделить данные csv файла с помощью библиотеки pandas? Может, дело в настройках компьютера/ноутбука?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Программе необходимо считать csv файл и вывести все значения, разделив данные по запятым.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', index_col='PassengerId')
print(data)
```

Пробовала разные способы: указывала явно sep=',', писала полностью имя файла(его путь), вставлять дополнительные параметры, писать код в других средах (я предпочитаю PyCharm, также использовала Jupyter Notebook, Wing IDE). Ничто не помогло. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что выводит программа. Как разделить строки по столбцам? На одном из форумов я прочитала, что это может быть дело в настройках компьютера. Где эти настройки тогда и что там менять (Windows 10)?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы часть исходных данных, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: что-то вы недоговариваете... По умолчанию `pd.read_csv` использует запятую в качестве разделителя. Насколько велика вероятность, что в `titanic.csv` использована какая-то экзотическая юникодная запятая вместо обычной?

Comment: @strawdog скорее всего, имеется в виду тренировочный датасет задачи Титаника на каггле: [`train.csv`](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv). @lazy_fox попробуй использовать ее вместо твоей.

Comment: @strawdog
https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_ea07570741a3ec966e284208f588e50e_titanic.csv?Expires=1566950400&Signature=ZIZaWkAPFVOnZep9XvgDT~odqdpORqhPzIgwncKhLEK4dryGY425qK61pYvzMkcwsvhJ~ybjEFW6KXXtO121ZyjKiyGNjmyTlWT8JmC-2mwfQDa5DqXwp2zbGrVKbTcLhmFHwgW3lHpVjioXT6SXu6OQSV1ooEEOT-b7iaMy~tQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A
К сожалению, я ещё не совсем поняла, как пользоваться сайтом, поэтому выше ссылка на файл.

Comment: @MaxU я не знаю что нужно сделать, поэтому и спрашиваю. На другом форуме я спрашивала, но у остальных данные разделяются. То же самое пробовала сделать на разных ПК, но безрезультатно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу воспроизвести указанное в вопросе поведение, используя файл по ссылке из комментариев...

```
In [6]: data = pd.read_csv(r'https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_ea07570741a3ec966e284208f588e50e_titanic.csv?Expires=1566950400&Signature=ZIZaWkAP
   ...: FVOnZep9XvgDT~odqdpORqhPzIgwncKhLEK4dryGY425qK61pYvzMkcwsvhJ~ybjEFW6KXXtO121ZyjKiyGNjmyTlWT8JmC-2mwfQDa5DqXwp2zbGrVKbTcLhmFHwgW3lHpVjioXT6SXu
   ...: 6OQSV1ooEEOT-b7iaMy~tQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A', index_col='PassengerId')

In [7]: data
Out[7]:
             Survived  Pclass                                     Name     Sex   Age  ...  Parch            Ticket  \
PassengerId                                                                           ...
1                   0       3                  Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0  ...      0         A/5 21171
2                   1       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence...  female  38.0  ...      0          PC 17599
3                   1       3                   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0  ...      0  STON/O2. 3101282
4                   1       1  Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily M...  female  35.0  ...      0            113803
5                   0       3                 Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0  ...      0            373450
6                   0       3                         Moran, Mr. James    male   NaN  ...      0            330877
7                   0       1                  McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J    male  54.0  ...      0             17463
...               ...     ...                                      ...     ...   ...  ...    ...               ...
885                 0       3                   Sutehall, Mr. Henry Jr    male  25.0  ...      0   SOTON/OQ 392076
886                 0       3     Rice, Mrs. William (Margaret Norton)  female  39.0  ...      5            382652
887                 0       2                    Montvila, Rev. Juozas    male  27.0  ...      0            211536
888                 1       1             Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith  female  19.0  ...      0            112053
889                 0       3  Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Car...  female   NaN  ...      2        W./C. 6607
890                 1       1                    Behr, Mr. Karl Howell    male  26.0  ...      0            111369
891                 0       3                      Dooley, Mr. Patrick    male  32.0  ...      0            370376

                Fare  Cabin Embarked
PassengerId
1             7.2500    NaN        S
2            71.2833    C85        C
3             7.9250    NaN        S
4            53.1000   C123        S
5             8.0500    NaN        S
6             8.4583    NaN        Q
7            51.8625    E46        S
...              ...    ...      ...
885           7.0500    NaN        S
886          29.1250    NaN        Q
887          13.0000    NaN        S
888          30.0000    B42        S
889          23.4500    NaN        S
890          30.0000   C148        C
891           7.7500    NaN        Q

[891 rows x 11 columns]
```

PS [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) использует запятую в качестве разделителя по умолчанию, **вне зависимости от настроек системы**

Comment: Если знаете, в чём тогда может быть проблема?

Comment: @lazy_fox, попробуйте запустить в `Jupyter` или в `ipython` код из моего ответа __без изменений__ и расскажите что получилось...

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! Помогло! Возможно, дело было в файле, я его импортировала с компьютера(заранее скачанный), а не по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла ещё 1 вещь, как вариант она даже проще. Дело в кодировке.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', index_col='PassengerId', encoding='cp1251')
print(data)
```